# how to use a typescript type in prisma model

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I have a Type Board that I want to use inside one of my prisma model
can someone guide me through the process of doing so, and I'm getting this error Type "Board" is neither a built-in type, nor refers to another model, custom type, or enum.

Board type is:

```
export type Board = {
  title: string;
  boardId?: string;
  id?: string;
  orgId: string;
  imageId: string;
  imageThumbUrl: string;
  imageFullUrl: string;
  imageUserName: string;
  imageLinkHTML: string;

  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
};
```

schema.prisma:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:./data/dev.db"
  // url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}


model List {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  title     String
  order     Int

  boardId   String
  board     Board @relation(fields: [boardId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  cards     Card[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([boardId])
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to use a typescript type Board inside a prisma schema file? ``` board     Board @relation...```

Comment: What would the database schema actually look like here? How would `Board`s be stored? Is it it's own table? If you want a `Board` table then you have to put that in the prisma schema file as it's own model.

Comment: @SlothOverlord yes

Comment: @AlexWayne `Board` table is stored in MockApi.io

Comment: So board is not in the prisma managed database at all? Then prisma can't possibly deliver that type, or manage that relationship.

Comment: @AlexWayne should I then fetch the data from that api into a prisma `Board` table?
if you know any resources please share them

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a typescript type inside a Prisma model

Prisma models can only reference other models and enums defined in that schema file.

You would either have to define a model for your Board, but that would require you to store the Board information inside of your database, or, you can your have the boardId stored for List model, and load it in a resolver or an api call.

Prisma way with storing Board data

```
model List {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  title     String
  order     Int

  boardId   String
  board     Board @relation(fields: [boardId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  cards     Card[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([boardId])
}

model Board {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  title String
  //... Other things
  imageLinkHTML: string;

  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

Or just have a List model that will be stored in the databse, and store the id of the board

```
model List {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  title     String
  order     Int

  boardId   String

  cards     Card[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([boardId])
}
```

And then when you get the Board from mockapi.io, extend the prisma type with your Board type. You can get the prisma type after using `npx prisma generate`

```
import { List } from "@prisma/client";


//Fetch List from your database using prisma
//Fetch Board from mockapi.io
//Combine List and Board data and Extend the List type with {board: Board}


//Inside of your getAllLists query:
const listData = await prisma.list.findUnique({where: {
id: yourId}}) //Get one List
const boardData: Board = await fetch("mockapi.io api") //Fetch one Board data from mockapi.io

const newListData: List & {board: Board} = {...listData, board: boardData}
```

Comment: Added an example at the end. You will have to handle the fetch yourself and adjust it based on your api requirements. But this will serve as a guideline

Answer (score 0):

> `Board` table is stored in MockApi.io

Then Prisma can't know about this.

In order to fetch a `Board` from `List`, you'd have to do something like this in code:

```
const list = await prisma.list.findUnique({ where: { id: listId } })
const board = await mockApiIoClient.board.findById(list.boardId) // psuedocode
```

And you'd remove this line from the schema file:

```
  board     Board @relation(fields: [boardId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
```

Since it's not a relationship that prisma is capable of managing.

Your code has to bridge the gap between the two systems. Which means it's not prisma's job the manage or provide the `Board` type.

Prisma generates typescript typesscript types from the database schema. Using a typescript type *in* the schema wouldn't really make sense.